# How to get numeric value from multiples of 10?

Tags: calculus, logic, quadratics

I have the following logic:

1 unit = 1 value

10 units = 2 value

100 units = 3 value

1000 units = 4 value

10000 units = 5 value ... etc

what is the formula where I can plug an arbitrary number of units and it will solve itself for the value and vice versa?

it would be something like X units = Y value

this must be simple but im not great at math, thanks for the help.

Comment: "*so 500 units should have = 3.5 value*" Why? Except for that, it looks like $\text{value} = 1 + \log_{10} \text{units}$.

Comment: well because its halfway in between 100 and 1000 and so halfway inbetween 3 and 4

Comment: But your scale is not linear. For example, $4$ is halfway between $3$ and $5$, but $1000$ is certainly *not* halfway between $100$ and $10000$. You may want to read up some more on the [log scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) and [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in general, because your question does not make a lot of sense as is now.

Comment: @fabrialis if you say that 500 will be 3.5 as its in between 100 and 1000, why do you not think that 50 units is 2 value? It's halfway between 1 and 100 units (1 and 3 values) in your scale.

Comment: you are right, it does not make sense, thanks for bringing it to my attention, ill remove the bit about 500 = 3.5. @dxiv 1+log10units. is what i needed thanks a lot=) you can submit it as answer please

Comment: @fabrialis Then see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%2B+log10%28n%29+for+n+in+%7B1%2C+10%2C+100%2C+1000%2C+10000%2C+100000%7D). It's $\,\text{value} = 1 + \log_{10} \text{units}\,$, or $\,\text{units} = 10^{\text{value} - 1}\,$. You can submit that as a self-answer once you are sure that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dxiv for the answer,

The solution for value is:

value=1+log10(units)

and for units is:

units=10^value−1

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).